# Transferir(colar) arquivos da área de transferência para um input de arquivos?

Tags: javascript, imagem, input, vue.js, área-de-transferência

Tenho o seguinte `input` de arquivos:

```
<input class="botao" @change="carregarFoto" type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*">
          <img :src="foto" style="width:192px;height:108px;" />


carregarFoto (e) {
  var arquivo = e.target.files
  if (!arquivo[0]) {
    return
  }
  var data = new FormData()
  data.append('media', arquivo[0])
  var reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    this.foto = e.target.result
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(arquivo[0])
}
```

E quero que quando eu selecione ele e pressione as teclas `ctrl` + `v` a imagem que eu esteja na área de transferência seja inserida nesse input. É possível fazer isso??

Obs.: Estou usando VueJS

Comment: Segue link da solução que precisa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000420/force-paste-event-to-encode-images-in-base64.

Comment: Muito bom, por favor adicione como resposta para que eu possa aceitar e caso alguém procure pela mesma pregunta consiga achar a solução

Comment: Pode postá-la, estou sem tempo de escrever uma resposta completa, mas fico feliz em poder ter ajudado.

Comment: Ok, vou escrever uma resposta, caso achar necessário editar, sinta-se a vontade...